# How to create new page in magento site

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I am trying to create a new page in magento ,in which I have to add some html and javascript.
For this ,I have created a module .
Contents of -> app\code\local\CompanyName\HelloWorld\etc\config.xml -

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
<modules>
    <CompanyName_Helloworld>
        <version>
            0.1.0
        </version>
    </CompanyName_Helloworld>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <helloworld>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>CompanyName_Helloworld</module>
                <frontName>Helloworld</frontName>
            </args>
        </helloworld>
    </routers>

</frontend>
```

Contents of -> app\code\local\CompanyName\HelloWorld\controllers\IndexController.php -

```
<?php
 class CompanyName_Helloworld_IndexController extends   Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
public function indexAction(){
    $this->loadLayout();
           $this->renderLayout();
    //echo "We're echoing just to show that this is what's called, normally you'd have some kind of redirect going on here";
  }
 }
```

?>

After doing all this when I goto domain/index.php/Helloworld 
I can see the header and  the footer,Now I want to add some "div" tags and javascript between them.
Please Explain how to do it.

Comment: Why don't you use CMS page instead?

Comment: Can you tell then ,that where to add html and javascript because When I paste the code in the content area.It is displayed as it is without rendering it.

Comment: There's a button to switch between WYSIWYG an HTML modes.

Comment: @ankit: You can add that as custom block.

Answer (score 9):

Insert to module's `config.xml`:

```
<frontend>
...
  <layout>
    <updates>
      <helloworld>
        <file>helloworld.xml</file>
      </helloworld>
    </updates>
  </layout>
</frontend>
```

Next add layout file `app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/helloworld.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <helloworld_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="helloworld/index" name="helloworld_any_block" template="helloworld/index.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </helloworld_index_index>
</layout>
```

Eventually add phtml file `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/helloworld/index.phtml` with any content.