# Magento 1.9 create new Hello World module

Tags: php, magento, module, magento-1.9

#### Hello, guys!

I really hope someone will help me with this.
I trying to make new module in magento 1.9.3.2, which show "Hello world!" from phtml file. I  created that step by step by this rules. Module is created, but when I open module (127.0.0.1/magento/helloworld) in browser, nothing appear, just empty this template.
[opened module in browser - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuIZk.jpg)

**Here is steps by what i guided:**
1. Module declaration:
     Create new xml file in  app/etc/modules/M4U_HelloWorld.xml 
    `<?xml version="1.0"?>
                 <config>
                       <modules>
                          <M4U_HelloWorld>
                               <active>true</active>
                               <codePool>local</codePool>
                          </M4U_HelloWorld>
                       </modules>
                 </config>`

2. Module configuration
       2.1. Create controller class in app/code/local/M4U/HelloWorld/controllers/IndexController.php

   `class M4U_HelloWorld_IndexController extends  Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
                       {
                         public function indexAction()
                         {
                            $this->loadLayout(array('default'));
                            $this->renderLayout();
                         }
                       }`

2.2. Create Block class in app/code/local/M4U/HelloWorld/Block/HelloWorld.php

```
class M4U_HelloWorld_Block_HelloWorld extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
                  {
                       // necessary methods
                  }
```

2.3. Create configuration xml in app/code/local/M4U/HelloWorld/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<global>
    <modules>
            <m4u_helloworld>
                    <version>0.1.0</version>
            </m4u_helloworld>
    </modules>
<blocks>
        <helloworld>
            <rewrite>
     <helloworld>M4U_HelloWorld_Block_HelloWorld</helloworld>
    </rewrite>
        </helloworld>
 </blocks>
    </global>
   <frontend>
            <routers>
                    <helloworld>
                            <use>standard</use>
                            <args>
                                  <module>M4U_HelloWorld</module>
                                  <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                            </args>
                    </helloworld>
            </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <helloworld>
                  <file>helloworld.xml</file>
            </helloworld>
        </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
```

3. Define frontend template
   3.1. Define page layout in app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/helloworld.xml
   `<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <layout version="0.1.0">
       <helloworld_index_index>
           <reference name="root">
               <action method="setTemplate">                  <template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
           </reference>
           <reference name="content">
               <block type="helloworld/helloworld" name="hello" template="helloworld/helloworld.phtml"/>
           </reference>
       </helloworld_index_index>
   </layout>`
4. Create template file in   app/design/frontend/default/default/template/helloworld/helloworld.phtml

Comment: instead of *127.0.0.1/magento/arturs* try *127.0.0.1/magento/helloworld* since that's what you've defined the URL as in the `<frontent><routers>` in config.xml

Comment: Oi, sorry, i forget change in this post, it was a helloworld

Comment: In `config.xml` you've got `<modules>` inside `<global>` - it should be root level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create new page in magento site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483097/how-to-create-new-page-in-magento-site)

Answer (score 4):

**TRIED AND TESTED**

[screenshot here](https://puu.sh/v4pZ6/073e1a2154.png)

you can display your helloworld template in your custom module, done some minor modifications to your code.

1. module declaration:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
          <modules>
             <M4U_HelloWorld>
                  <active>true</active>
                  <codePool>local</codePool>
             </M4U_HelloWorld>
          </modules>
    </config>
   ```
2. creating the folder structure and add the files

> A. app/code/local/M4U/HelloWorld/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <m4u_helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </m4u_helloworld>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>M4U_HelloWorld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <helloworld module="M4U_HelloWorld">
                    <file>M4U_HelloWorld.xml</file>
                </helloworld>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <helloworld>
                <class>M4U_HelloWorld_Block</class>
            </helloworld>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

> B. app/code/local/M4U/HelloWorld/block/HelloWorld.php

```
class M4U_HelloWorld_Block_HelloWorld extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

}
```

> C. app/code/local/M4U/HelloWorld/controllers/IndexController.php

```
class M4U_HelloWorld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        echo 'hello world';
        $this->loadLayout();  //This function read all layout files and loads them in memory
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

> D. app/design/frontend/ * theme base* / * mytheme * /layout/M4U_HelloWorld.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <helloworld_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">                  
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="helloworld/helloworld" name="hello" template="helloworld/helloworld.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </helloworld_index_index>
</layout>
```

> E. app/design/frontend/ * theme base* / * mytheme * /template/helloworld/helloworld.php

```
echo 'im a template block';
```

Answer (score 1):

For create HelloWorld module in Magento 1.9 please follow below tutorial URL.

URL: http://blog.iyngaran.info/create-custom-module-helloworld-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

As Per [Inchoo Article](http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/magento-hello-world-module-extension/) :

> We will start by creating a simple “Hello world” module. However, you
>   will soon see that simple takes a new meaning with Magento. Creating a
>   bare bone module requires at least two files in Magento. For your
>   module to work you need /app/etc/modules/MyCompany_MyModule.xml,
>   app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/etc/config.xml. But, barebone module
>   will not give you a “Hello developer” -So, we need to add few more
>   files to the game.
>
> file 1: /app/etc/modules/Inchoo_HelloDeveloper.xml
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config>
>     <modules>
>         <Inchoo_HelloDeveloper>
>             <active>true</active>
>             <codePool>local</codePool>
>         </Inchoo_HelloDeveloper>
>     </modules>
> </config>
> ```
>
> file 2: app/code/local/Inchoo/HelloDeveloper/etc/config.xml
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config>
>     <modules>
>         <Inchoo_HelloDeveloper>
>             <version>0.1.0</version>
>         </Inchoo_HelloDeveloper>
>     </modules>    
>     <frontend>
>         <routers>
>             <Inchoo_HelloDeveloper_SomeFreeRouterName1>
>                 <use>standard</use>
>                 <args>
>                     <module>Inchoo_HelloDeveloper</module>
>                     <frontName>inchoo-hellodeveloper</frontName>
>                 </args>
>             </Inchoo_HelloDeveloper_SomeFreeRouterName1>
>         </routers>
>     </frontend>    
> </config>
> ```
>
> file 3:
>   app/code/local/Inchoo/HelloDeveloper/controllers/IndexController.php
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> class Inchoo_HelloDeveloper_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
> {
>     public function indexAction()
>     {
>         echo 'Hello developer...';
>     }
>
>     public function sayHelloAction()
>     {
>         echo 'Hello one more time...';
>     }
> }
> ?>
> ```
>
> Altough extremely simple, file 3 shows us one important thing: Naming
>   connvention. Note the name of the class. Your moudle classes should
>   keep names in form of MyCompany_MyModule_FileName, or in case of block
>   and modules: MyCompany_MyModule_Block_FileName or
>   MyCompany_MyModule_Module_FileName.